# DataTables - sorting tables with formatted values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to sort DataTables with formatted values?

I need to format the values in the table but then sorting won't work.. How can you use formatted values in the cells?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-value="10000.45">10,000.45</td>
        <td data-value="458">458.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$('table').dataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try with `aoColumns` with `sType=numeric` ?
[This](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) one may be helpful for you.

Comment: isn't it possible to add a custom value on the `td` tag??

Comment: Im not exactly sure on how to sort based on an attribute value. But [http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/sorting_plugin.html] this link is providing some useful tips.